# Help understanding parsing a JSON object using .class

Tags: apex, rest-api

I have made an API request and retrieved the data and performed what I needed to do. I understand what the  code below is doing but would like if someone could tell clarify if I am correct or spread some knowledge.

The retrieved result from the GET request is a List of JSON objects I cast the deserialized response to a list of type `MockObject` as per the JSON objects retuned.

I dont know what is happening here `List<MockResponse>.class` does this for each JSON object in the list create a list of the MockObject variables and then add it to the `responseList`? The output is

> (MockResponse:[code=BTC, name=Bitcoin, rate=1],
> MockResponse:[code=BCH, name=Bitcoin Cash, rate=181], ... )

```
    List<MockResponse> responseList;
    if(response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        // Here is the line of code 
        responseList = (List<MockResponse>)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), List<MockResponse>.class);
        System.debug(responseList);
        return responseList.get(2).rate;

    }


// Mock the Json object which is returned by the API
public class MockResponse{
    public String code;
    public String name;
    public String rate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not just casting the data, but is informing the deserializer that the shape of the data is `List<MockResponse>.class`. The deserializer uses this information - such as the field names and types of `MockResponse` - to determine what to look for and what type conversion is needed and to instantiate the returned objects.

If you want to confirm that everything parsed OK you can use:

```
System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(responseList));
```

to go back to JSON. (Your `System.debug(responseList);` presents an abbreviated form of the data by design.)

Comment: IMO easier to output to debug log as a single line and then prettify elsewhere (such as `beautifier.io`).